# Problem with double precision and smartpointer in ITK

Tags: c++, fft, fftw, itk

The problem I have is that I open an Image from a GUI using Qt (through the class I created  ImageFrame, this class has defined the PixelType as follows:

```
typedef double PixelType;
typedef itk::Image<PixelType,2> ImageType;
```

and after the extraction of the image, I would lie to make a FFT which input is real data.
The error says: it cannot be converted the third parameter of ‘itk::SmartPointer’ to ‘double*’ with and object of the ImageFrame class (which has defined the pixeltype as double).

> 1>.\prueba_r01.cpp(126) : error C2664: 'fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d' : no se puede convertir el parámetro 3 de 'itk::SmartPointer' a 'double *'
>   1>        with
>   1>        [
>   1>            TObjectType=itk::Image
>   1>        ]
>   1>  No hay disponible ningún operador de conversión definido por el usuario que pueda realizar esta conversión, o bien no se puede llamar al operador

Now I cannot understand why it cannot calculate the fft if the pixel are in double format.
Does anyone can give me an idea of how to fix this problem? Thank you all so much in advance!

Comment: why people are downvoting? this question is absolutely legitimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `image.Pointer()` is a smart pointer object, a wrapper around the read pointer to your data. You must pass `image.Pointer().GetPointer()` to fftw.

Comment: So easy as you said, thanks so much for your time in such a simple thing, i am very gratufll

Comment: It was not enough to do this, the information is lost somehow there is no data the double pointer in* after this code: " double *in = (double*) imagen.GetPointer()

Answer (score 1):

To get the pixel data (a double*), you need to use

```
image->GetBufferPointer();
```

This will return a double*, that can be passed into FFTW.